# Using cancancan with my own authentication request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan

I have my own authentication request like this in my ApplicationController:

```
attr_reader :current_user

def authenticate_request
    @token ||= JsonWebToken.decode(http_auth_header)
    @current_user = User.validate(@token)

    json_response({message: 'You must be logged in...'}, :unauthorized) unless @current_user
end
```

For each controller, I have put this to validate token:

```
 before_action :authenticate_request
```

When using with cancancan, I'm adding extra validation permision in abilitiy.rb...

After I added `check_authorization` it asked me to add `authorize_resource` so I did it and now it's giving me this error: `You are not authorized to access this page.`

I have no idea how to configure and how can @current_user can be use in ability.rb?

I tried to do:

```
alias_method :current_user, :authenticate_request
```

tried to following here:

https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/changing-defaults

If I only add `load_and_authorize_resource` the ability.rb user works fine, but do not wish to put this every controller file.

Comment: If you have a `current_user` method available in your controller and views, cancancan will use it, with no customizations needed. Maybe post the relevant code of your controller and your ability.rb for further help

Comment: My Ability is the same as generated, and my controller has only  before_action :authenticate_request and crud methods. and what you mean current_user method avaible in controllers and views? @current_user can be accessed in all controller and views.

Comment: Well, I really understand why my user is nil, because AppController fire first check_authorization and authorize_resource and after my controller is fire my authentication request, which is giving error... so basically I removed every :authenticate_request in my controllers and moved up to AppController and worked nice